# Pytest mocking nested object

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am trying to understand how to overcome an issue with mocking a python attribute coming from an imported module within a constructor.

I have a simplified Tableau python class which is defined like this:

```py
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd
from os import environ

class Tableau(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # BYPASS ALL OF THIS AUTHENTICATION?
        self.server = TSC.Server(environ.get("TABLEAU_URL"), use_server_version=False)
        self.server.version = environ.get("TABLEAU_API_VERSION")
        self.tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(
            environ.get("TABLEAU_TOKEN_NAME"),
            environ.get("TABLEAU_TOKEN_VALUE"),
            site_id="",
        )
        self.tableau_server = self.server.auth.sign_in(self.tableau_auth)

    def get_all_views(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        data = []
        # HOW TO MOCK self.tableau_server.views?
        for view in TSC.Pager(self.tableau_server.views):
            data.append([view.name, view.id, view.workbook_id])

        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["View", "Id", "Workbook_Id"])
        return df
```

How can I mock the output of `self.tableau_server.views` in get_all_views() from pytest to return a mocked list of views...

```
[
  (id=1, name="view_a", "workbook_id"=1),
  (id=2, name="view_b", "workbook_id"=2),
  (id=3, name="view_c", "workbook_id"=3),
]
```

*Note - the return value needs to be iterable

Here's what I tried so far... I have been running into "module not found" errors and errors within the constructor - so I think mocking is not working correctly.

```py
from pytest_mock import mocker
from connectors import Tableau
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal


def get_mocked_tableau_views(mocker):
    a = mocker.Mock()
    a.name = "a"
    a.id = 1
    a.workbook_id = 1
    b = mocker.Mock()
    b.name = "b"
    b.id = 2
    b.workbook_id = 2
    c = mocker.Mock()
    c.name = "c"
    c.id = 3
    c.workbook_id = 3

    return mocker.Mock(return_value=iter([a, b, c]))


def test_initialize(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(TSC, "__init__", return_value=None)
    mocker.patch.object(TSC.__init__, "server", return_value=None)
    mocker.patch.object(TSC.__init__, "server.version", return_value=None)


def test_get_all_views(mocker):
    mocked_tsc = mocker.MagicMock()
    mocked_tsc.Server.auth.sign_in = "test"

    with mocker.patch(
        "connectors.tableau.Tableau.tableau_server.views",
        return_value=get_mocked_tableau_views,
    ):
        tab = Tableau()
        df_actual = tab.get_all_views()
        df_expected = pd.DataFrame(
            {"Id": [1, 2, 3], "View": ["a", "b", "c"], "Workbook_Id": [1, 2, 3]}
        )
        assert_frame_equal(df_actual, df_expected)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer to the question:
*# HOW TO MOCK self.tableau_server.views?*
present in the method `get_all_views()` of the class `Tableau`.

I don't use pytest, but only the module `mock`.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

def get_mocked_tableau_views():
    a = mock.Mock()
    a.name = "a"
    a.id = 1
    a.workbook_id = 1
    b = mock.Mock()
    b.name = "b"
    b.id = 2
    b.workbook_id = 2
    c = mock.Mock()
    c.name = "c"
    c.id = 3
    c.workbook_id = 3
    return iter([a, b, c])

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_all_views(self):
        tab = Tableau()
        with mock.patch.object(tab, 'tableau_server') as mock_tableau_server:
            mock_tableau_server.views.side_effect = self.get_mocked_tableau_views
            df_actual = tab.get_all_views()
            df_expected = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [1, 2, 3], "View": ["a", "b", "c"], "Workbook_Id": [1, 2, 3]})
            self.assertEqual(df_expected, df_actual)
```

I think you have to adjust a bit my code to execute it on your system. I hope this answer can be useful for you.